# Cannot set an instance variable for an object using Django

Tags: python, django

I cannot seem to set an instance variable using Django.

What I want to happen is:

```
a,b = User(), User()
a.set_status('abc')
b.set_status('def')
b.get_status()
>>> 'def'
a.get_status()
>>> 'abc'
```

Unfortunately, what keeps happening is:

```
a,b = User(), User()
a.set_status('abc')
b.set_status('def')
b.get_status()
>>> 'def'
a.get_status()
>>> 'def'
```

I believe this is because the `status` variable is a class variable rather than an instance variable.  How do I make the code behave like I want above?  My models are below.

```
class Status(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, status = '', time=datetime.datetime.min, *args, **kwargs):
        self.status = status
        self.status_time = time
        super(Status, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_status(self, s):
        self.status = s
        self.status_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.save()
    def get_status(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if now-self.status_time<datetime.timedelta(minutes=15):
            return self.status
        return None


class User(models.Model):
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    friends = ListField()
    status = Status()

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, fid, friends):
        k = User()
        k.facebook_id = fid
        k.friends = friends
        k.status = Status()
        k.status.save()
        k.save()

    def login(self, facebook_friends):
        self.friends = facebook_friends
        self.save()

    def set_status(self, status):
        self.status.set_status(status)
        #return matching statuses

    def get_status(self):
        return self.status.get_status()
```

Comment: Hmm, have you read the docs or followed the tutorial on models and their relations? I've never seen models implemented like this before...

Comment: @Ngenator is right. In your User model, you should change `status = Status()` by `status = models.ForeignKey(Status)`. It is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `status` attribute is **global**. It's part of the `User` class not of the actual instance. So it's actually normal behavior. `set_status()` will set a global `status` available to every `User` instance via `get_status()`.

You should redesign your model. You don't really need the `Status` class anyway. You can have that business logic directly in your User methods `set_status` and `get_status`. But if you need to keep track of every status change then just have a ForeignKey to a Status model.